# my function SubmitRecord() not functioning well in app sheets, whats the core problem

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an issue. I tried to made a google sheet sidebar form with appscript. I followed tutorial from youtub* with modified my code. Theres one problem in here, that the function "SubmitRecord()" cannot functioning well. When the button click, nothing response happen. I just wonder what is the main problem with my code.

This is the gs. code

```
function AddArsipForm()
  { 
    var form = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Arsip').setTitle('TAMBAH ARSIP');
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(form);
  }
    

function addMenu()
{
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Custom');
  menu.addItem('Tambah Arsip', 'AddArsipForm');
  menu.addToUi(); 
}

function onOpen(e)
{
  addMenu(); 
}

function AddRecord(nomor, klasifikasi, kode_unitcipta, uraian, kurunwaktu_awal, kurunwaktu_akhir, tingkat_perkembangan, media_simpan, kondisi_fisik, jumlah_berkas, kode_ruang, nomor_lemari, nomor_boks, nomor_folder) {
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  if(nomor != '' && klasifikasi != '' && kode_unitcipta != '' && uraian != '' && kurunwaktu_awal != '' && kurunwaktu_akhir != '' && tingkat_perkembangan != '' && media_simpan != '' && kondisi_fisik != '' && jumlah_berkas != '' && kode_ruang != '' && nomor_lemari != '' && nomor_boks != '' && nomor_folder!= '')
  {
    dataSheet.appendRow([nomor, klasifikasi, kode_unitcipta, uraian, kurunwaktu_awal, kurunwaktu_akhir, tingkat_perkembangan, media_simpan, kondisi_fisik, jumlah_berkas, kode_ruang, nomor_lemari, nomor_boks, nomor_folder, new Date()]);
    return "<span style=\"font-weight: bold\" >Data telah terekam!</span>";
  }
  else
  {
    return "<span style=\"font-weight: bold; color: red\" >Data Belum Lengkap</span>";
  }
}

function getAllKlasifikasi()
{
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var klasifikasiSheet = ss.getSheetByName("KODE KLASIFIKASI");
  var [headers, ...data] = klasifikasiSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  return data;
}
```

This is the HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<style>
.narrow
{
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
</style>
<script>
function SubmitRecord()
{
  document.getElementById("displayReturn").innerHTML = "";
  var nomor = document.getElementById("nomor").value;
  var klasifikasi = document.getElementById("klasifikasi").value;
  var kode_unitcipta = document.getElementById("kode_unitcipta").value;
  var kode_unitcipta = document.getElementById("uraian").value;
  var kurunwaktu_awal = document.getElementById("kurunwaktu_awal").value;
  var kurunwaktu_akhir = document.getElementById("kurunwaktu_akhir").value;
  var tingkat_perkembangan = document.getElementById("tingkat_perkembangan").value;
  var media_simpan = document.getElementById("media_simpan").value;
  var kondisi_fisik = document.getElementById("kondisi_fisik").value;
  var jumlah_berkas = document.getElementById("jumlah_berkas").value;
  var kode_ruang = document.getElementById("kode_ruang").value;
  var nomor_lemari = document.getElementById("nomor_lemari").value;
  var nomor_boks = document.getElementById("nomor_boks").value;
  var nomor_folder = document.getElementById("nomor_folder").value;
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(returnBack)
  .AddRecord(nomor, klasifikasi, kode_unitcipta, uraian, kurunwaktu_awal, kurunwaktu_akhir, tingkat_perkembangan, media_simpan, kondisi_fisik, jumlah_berkas, kode_ruang, nomor_lemari, nomor_boks, nomor_folder);
}

function returnBack(stringBack)
{
  document.getElementById("displayReturn").innerHTML = stringBack;
  document.getElementById("nomor").value = '';
  document.getElementById("klasifikasi").value = '';
  document.getElementById("kode_unitcipta").value = '';
  document.getElementById("uraian").value = '';
  document.getElementById("kurunwaktu_awal").value = '';
  document.getElementById("kurunwaktu_akhir").value = '';
  document.getElementById("tingkat_perkembangan").value = '';
  document.getElementById("media_simpan").value = '';
  document.getElementById("kondisi_fisik").value = '';
  document.getElementById("jumlah_berkas").value = '';
  document.getElementById("kode_ruang").value = '';
  document.getElementById("nomor_lemari").value = '';
  document.getElementById("nomor_boks").value = '';
  document.getElementById("nomor_folder").value = '';
}

function GetKlasifikasi()
{
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) 
  {
    var klasifikasi = document.getElementById("klasifikasi"); 
    console.log(ar);
    
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = "";
    option.text = "";
    klasifikasi.appendChild(option);
    
    ar.forEach(function(item, index) 
    {    
      let option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = item[1];
      option.text = item[0];
      klasifikasi.appendChild(option);    
    });
  
  }).getAllKlasifikasi();
};
</script>



  </head>
  <body>
<form>
  <div style="padding: 10px" >

  <div class="form-row" >
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 narrow" >
  <label for="nomor" style="margin-bottom: 0rem" >Nomor</label>
  <input type="text" id="nomor" class="form-control" />
  </div> 
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 narrow" >
  <label for="klasifikasi" style="margin-bottom: 0rem" >Klasifikasi</label>
  <select id="klasifikasi" class="form-control" ></select>
  </div> 
  </div>

  <div class="form-row" >
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 narrow" >
  <label for="last_name" style="margin-bottom: 0rem" >Last Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="last_name" class="form-control" />
  </div> 
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 narrow" >
  <label for="street" style="margin-bottom: 0rem" >Street</label>
  <input type="text" id="kode_unitcipta" class="form-control" />
  </div> 
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 narrow" >
  <label for="city" style="margin-bottom: 0rem" >City</label>
  <input type="text" id="uraian" class="form-control" />
  </div> 
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 narrow" >
  <label for="city" style="margin-bottom: 0rem" >City</label>
  <input type="text" id="kurunwaktu_awal" class="form-control" />
  </div> 
  </div>

    <div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 narrow" >
  <label for="city" style="margin-bottom: 0rem" >City</label>
  <input type="text" id="kurunwaktu_akhir" class="form-control" />
  </div> 
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 narrow" >
  <label for="city" style="margin-bottom: 0rem" >City</label>
  <input type="text" id="tingkat_perkembangan" class="form-control" />
  </div> 
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 narrow" >
  <label for="city" style="margin-bottom: 0rem" >City</label>
  <input type="text" id="media_simpan" class="form-control" />
  </div> 
  </div>

 <div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 narrow" >
  <label for="city" style="margin-bottom: 0rem" >City</label>
  <input type="text" id="kondisi_fisik" class="form-control" />
  </div> 
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 narrow" >
  <label for="city" style="margin-bottom: 0rem" >City</label>
  <input type="text" id="jumlah_berkas" class="form-control" />
  </div> 
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 narrow" >
  <label for="city" style="margin-bottom: 0rem" >City</label>
  <input type="text" id="kode_ruang" class="form-control" />
  </div> 
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 narrow" >
  <label for="city" style="margin-bottom: 0rem" >City</label>
  <input type="text" id="nomor_lemari" class="form-control" />
  </div> 
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 narrow" >
  <label for="city" style="margin-bottom: 0rem" >City</label>
  <input type="text" id="nomor_boks" class="form-control" />
  </div> 
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 narrow" >
  <label for="city" style="margin-bottom: 0rem" >City</label>
  <input type="text" id="nomor_folder" class="form-control" />
  </div> 
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 narrow" >
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SubmitRecord()" class="btn btn-primary" />
  </div> 
  </div>

  </form>
  
  <div id="displayReturn" ></div>
  </div>
  <script>GetKlasifikasi(); </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no way to test this but assuming your server side code works as it should.

First I would put all of the script into the body section of the page.  Secondly there is a misplaced `</div>` as I've shown below.  Third I like to use indenting to identify blocks of code/html.  And I would have put all the values from SubmitRecord into an array and then passed the array to the server side function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <style>
      .narrow
      {
        margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <div style="padding: 10px" >

        <div class="form-row" >
          <div class="form-group col-md-6 narrow" >
            <label for="nomor" style="margin-bottom: 0rem" >Nomor</label>
            <input type="text" id="nomor" class="form-control" />
          </div> 
        </div>
        .
        .
        .
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6 narrow" >
            <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SubmitRecord()" class="btn btn-primary" />
          </div> 
        </div>
        
      </div>  <! -- this div was misplaced --> 

    </form>
  
    <div id="displayReturn" ></div>
    <! -- </div>  --> 
    <script>
      function SubmitRecord() {
        document.getElementById("displayReturn").innerHTML = "";
        var nomor = document.getElementById("nomor").value;
        .
        .
        .
        var nomor_folder = document.getElementById("nomor_folder").value;
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(returnBack)
          .AddRecord(nomor, klasifikasi, kode_unitcipta, uraian, kurunwaktu_awal, kurunwaktu_akhir, tingkat_perkembangan, media_simpan, kondisi_fisik, jumlah_berkas, kode_ruang, nomor_lemari, nomor_boks, nomor_folder);
      }

      function returnBack(stringBack) {
        document.getElementById("displayReturn").innerHTML = stringBack;
        .
        .
        .
        document.getElementById("nomor_folder").value = '';
      }

      function GetKlasifikasi() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) 
        {
          var klasifikasi = document.getElementById("klasifikasi");
          .
          .
          .
 
        }).getAllKlasifikasi();
      };
      
      GetKlasifikasi();
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```